# Order by LOCATE MySql

Tags: mysql, locate

I'm trying to retrieve the data set by locating a string based on its occurrence, check the below query -

```
select name, LOCATE('test', name) 
from afkapi_dev.articles 
where name like '%test%' 
order by LOCATE('test', name) ASC
```

The result set is -

[image]

Result set is perfectly fine, but the issue here is the ordering.
Can anyone explain why **"testing"** is listed above **"test low"** and also suggest a way to make this happen.

Thank you

Comment: You are only ordering by `LOCATE()`. Both the cases have locate result as 1. If you want to do next level ordering, you need to specify further details about what should be the criteria for the same.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thanks for the response. Can you please suggest on how to achieve this.

Comment: `ORDER BY LOCATE(...), name`???

Comment: @SalmanA Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking to do further sorting on `name`. For multiple level sorting, you can specify different columns/expressions in `ORDER BY` clause, separated by comma, with respective sorting order `[ASC or DESC]`

Also, you can alias the `LOCATE(..)` expression in the `SELECT` clause, and reuse that in the `ORDER BY`. This should prevent re-computation of `LOCATE(..)` values.

```
select name, LOCATE('test', name) AS location 
from afkapi_dev.articles 
where name like '%test%' 
order by location ASC, name ASC
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped :)

Comment: The query you provided doesn't solve the issue I'm facing

Comment: @SantoshSGowda what is the issue ? Can you elaborate. Maybe I can revise the query. My current query solves your given problem statement. And this is not how Stack Overflow works. If you have a new question, you should post a new problem.

Comment: @SantoshSGowda and why did you say: "Thanks! That helped :)"

Comment: The fact that you said 'order by' clause can have more criteria helped